# limit column in database with UPDATE

Tags: php, mysql

I have a `turns` col. which updated every half an hour and add 5 turns to every user on my website.

I want to make a limit, for example 300, and every user who has 295 or more will be updated to 300, no more or less.

This is my query right now:

```
UPDATE `user_d` SET turns=turns+5 WHERE ID='".$id."'
```

If I'll add "WHERE turns < 300" users who has 298 for example will jump to 303 (over the limit), how can I limited it to 300?

Thx! my english isn't very strong and I tryied to make it understandable, but please ask me to try and explain better if you don't understood what I meant.

Comment: If you know what time each user started then why bother 'storing' this at all!?!

Comment: every user uses the turns diffrently, it isn't about time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use sql case, get turns below 296 to limit it 300

```
 UPDATE
       `user_d`
    SET
        turns
        (
            CASE
                WHEN
                    ((turns) < 296)
                THEN
                   turns=turns+5
                ELSE
                    (turns)
            END
        )
    WHERE
       ID='".$id."'
```

Comment: Thank you!! the `(turns)` part is where I put `turns=300` am I right?